# Installing Multiple OS and prepare the Partitioning

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, mint, fedora

1-I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 or Mint 17 along side with Windows 7 and also I want to install Fedora 20 on my HDD so it will be 3 operating systems, is that possible ?

2-How I can prepare the partitioning manually ?

3-what should i do to make the machine successfully boot-able for 2 or 3 OS ?

Comment: I think Fedora's default install is LVM with a separate /boot partition. But LVM is only an advantage if you have the entire drive set for LVM and it still is a bit more advanced. Better to create ext4 partition in advanced and manually install Fedora to just that ext4 partition not with LVM. Your last install will be the one with grub in MBR and controlling boot. You can easily reset that, but easier to install system you will use the most last. You also may want smaller system partitions and a larger shared data partition. If Windows also a option then shared data should be NTFS formatted.

Comment: Can you clarify your 2nd question a bit more?  The phrase "prepare the partitioning manually" is too vague.  Do you need the exact steps or tools needed to do it or just the overview of how it is done?

Comment: I need to know in details how to prepare the partitions and what do i need to do it and how to do it ( Prepare the hard disk for installing WIN7 and Ubuntu, Mint or Fedora ) which OS should i install first and Make all the operating systems boot-able when needed.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have 3 or more operating systems on your HD.

You must first of all install windows, and after that install the other Linux operating systems (in any order you prefer).

When you install Ubuntu, Mint or Fedora, they also install grub, the multiboot boot-loader, that checks if there are already one or more operating systems and allows the multi-boot.

If you install windows after linux, the boot-loader is overwritten by windows and you can't access to linux again, but only to windows.

When you install linux for the first time, there is the possibility to manually manage the partitions, so you can:

- resize the windows partition (it has an NTFS file system, or FAT for older versions)
- add one or more partitions for linux (you should choose the "ext4 with journaling" file system).
- You must also add a SWAP partition, that is needed by linux systems. This partition should be at least as big as the RAM memory of your system.

Summarizing, you need:

- 1 swap partition (at least as big as your RAM memory)
- 1 ext4 partition for every linux OS you want to install
- 1 ntfs partition for windows
- (optional) 1 ntfs partition for keeping data shared among different operating systems (as suggested by oldfred)

If you want to prepare the partitions at the begininning, you can use gparted in linux or partition magic in windows (but I suggest you to do it in linux).

I think the easiest way is to create a USB pendrive with the linux distribution, start you pc from this pendrive and start the installation process, during which you can create all the partitions you want of the size you want.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i need to know how to prepare it manually.

Comment: What do you mean with "manually"?

Comment: Anyway I modified a bit my answer, hope it helps.